# Get data on click and bind it in pug

Tags: pug

Here I am making a call to node server on click and i am not able to bind the data to jade template. 
Can you please let me know, how to bind.

In HTML,

```js
function loadMore() {
     $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/get_more_posts',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function() {

                // do nothing as the content rendered on the server side
            },
            error: function() {
               // generate an error
            }

        });
```

```html
div(onclick="loadMore(5)") Load More
        p #{message}
```

Below code I have written in server.js. I am not sure what to write in render in place of 'get_more_posts'.

```
    app.get('/get_more_posts', function(req, res) {
   res.render('get_more_posts',{
                    message: 'Thank you! We will be calling you shortly.'
                });
});
```

I need to bind this message on load more click.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Have you tried adding the event handler a different way?

Comment: No, I haven't tried to add event handler any other way.  I am getting error because of using 'get_more_posts' in res.render. I don't know any other way to bind. Can you please explain me here.

Comment: The issue isn't due to how you are adding the event handler if the error is because of `get_more_posts`. When you call your server to get more posts, it should not be rendering anything (because it's being called by ajax), instead it should be returning the data that you want to present. So your ajax call, which currently has the comment `do nothing as the content is rendered on the server side`, should instead be receiving the content `success: function(content) {` and then with the given content, create the appropriate markup

Comment: How can i add data that is obtained in ajax sucess to jade template.

Comment: Is there any jade tutorial to learn completely how to bind dynamic data to fetch on click from node server and bind data to jade template, Also lazy loading of content to append to array in jade template.

Comment: The jade template is being rendered server side, your ajax is happening after it's already done. You will have to create the html with javascript from the content returned from the server and then append it with javascript

Comment: @Joe Lissner, Do you have any sample code for this. So that, I will be able to understand in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

As requested, here is a sample that should get you pointed in the right direction. I had to do it as an answer because a comment would have been too long.

#### Front End js

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/my-test',
    success: function(data) {
        $('.js-test').test(data.heading);
    }
});
```

#### jade/pug

```
h2.js-test This is my old heading
```

#### Node js

```
app.get('/my-test', function(req, res) {
    res.send({heading: 'This is my new heading'});
});
```

In this example, it will change every `h2` with a class of `js-test` to have the text to to *"This is my new heading"* on load.

Comment: https://codepen.io/ashok123osm/pen/YZgjKO   . I need to update array in ajax. Can you please let me know, How can i update array from ajax. In the code sample i need to append "dataToAppend" array to 'arr' on click.

Comment: [https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YZgbbv](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YZgbbv) To set up the ajax, you need to set up the route similar to what I showed you above, I updated the javascript in your example to give you an example of how to create the html when you hit submit.